# How to compress or stack a pandas dataframe along the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas dataframe with several columns, however lets focus on two:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['hey how are you', 'fine thanks',1], 
                    ['good to know', 'yes, and you',2],
                    ['I am fine','ok',3],
                    ['see you','bye!',4]],columns=list('ABC'))
df
```

Out:

```
    A                   B           C
0   hey how are you     fine thanks 1
1   good to know    yes, and you    2
2   I am fine             ok        3
3   see you             bye!        4
```

From the previous data frame how can I compress two specific columns into a single pandas dataframe carrying out the values of the other columns? For example:

```
    A                C
0   hey how are you  1
1   fine thanks      1
2   good to know     2
3   yes, and you     2
4   I am fine        3
5   ok               3
6   see you          4
7   bye!             4
```

I tried to:

```
df = df['A'].stack()
df = df.groupby(level=0)
df
```

However, it doesnt work. Any idea of how to achieve the new format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will drop the column names, but gets the job done:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['hey how are you', 'fine thanks'], 
                    ['good to know', 'yes, and you'],
                    ['I am fine','ok'],
                    ['see you','bye!']],columns=list('AB'))

df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0    hey how are you
1        fine thanks
2       good to know
3       yes, and you
4          I am fine
5                 ok
6            see you
7               bye!
dtype: object
```

The default stack behaviour keeps the column names:

```
df.stack()

0  A    hey how are you
   B        fine thanks
1  A       good to know
   B       yes, and you
2  A          I am fine
   B                 ok
3  A            see you
   B               bye!
dtype: object
```

You can select the columns for stacking if you have more of them, just use the column indexing:

```
df[["A", "B"]].stack()
```

With additional columns, things get tricky, you need to align indices by dropping one level (containing columns):

```
df["C"] = range(4)

stacked = df[["A", "B"]].stack()
stacked.index = stacked.index.droplevel(level=1)

stacked

0    hey how are you
0        fine thanks
1       good to know
1       yes, and you
2          I am fine
2                 ok
3            see you
3               bye!
dtype: object
```

Now we can concat with `C` column:

```
pd.concat([stacked, df["C"]], axis=1)

                 0  C
0  hey how are you  0
0      fine thanks  0
1     good to know  1
1     yes, and you  1
2        I am fine  2
2               ok  2
3          see you  3
3             bye!  3
```

Comment: Added an example of how to select columns for stacking now.

Comment: I tried it out but still cant carry out the value of `col C`

Comment: I tried with: `reset_index(drop=False)` however doesnt keep the vals of col C

Comment: Updated the answer to factor in C column.

Comment: What if you dont know the range?

Comment: For C column? That's just an example I used to fill in the values. It should work with arbitrary values. Try it out with your data!

Comment: I got: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183459/discussion-between-pawroman-and-anon).

Answer (score 1):

You can `flatten()` (or `reshape(-1, )`) the `value`s of the DataFrame, which are stored as a numpy array:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten(), columns=['A'])

                 A
0  hey how are you
1      fine thanks
2     good to know
3     yes, and you
4        I am fine
5               ok
6          see you
7             bye!
```

*Comments:* The default behaviour of `np.ndarray.flatten` and `np.ndarray.reshape` is what you want, which is to vary the column index faster than the row index in the original array. This is so-called row-major (C-style) order. To vary the row index faster than the column index, pass in `order='F'` for column-major, Fortran-style ordering. Docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: Thanks! But what about if I have other columns?... is there anyway to keep the values in another column?

Answer (score -2):

What you may be looking for is [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

It accepts "a sequence or mapping of Series, DataFrame, or Panel objects", so you can pass a `list` of your `DataFrame` objects selecting the columns (which will be `pd.Series` when indexed for a single column).

```
df3 = pd.concat([df['A'], df['B']])
```